# How to make iterator to start from a specific index?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, iterator

I want to use iterator over a string from a specific index which is not the beginning, without using slicing. Is there a way doing this? I'm using python 3.2

***Edit:*** I need to write a  generator function that gets 2 arguments: iterator over an iterable consisted of chars, which may be infinite, and a pattern.
the function need to return the indexes of the starting occurrence of the pattern in the iterable. I name the generator g for the rest of the question.
**if the pattern length is m, the efficiency of the func should be O(m)**

for exmaple: string: abababab, pattern: abab

so we will get:

next(g)

0

next(g)

2

next(g)

4

Comment: because I have to do it multiple times and it won't be efficient

Comment: @CnR Why do you think so? Did you benchmark for efficiency?

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself to solve your problem? Any code you could provide would be helpful for people helping you.

Comment: Have you researched about it? Whay have you found?

Comment: Unless the string is HUGE, I doubt that you'll be able to do any faster than string slicing.

Comment: the string is huge. I will edit the question

Comment: It's impossible, O(len(pattern)) is independent of iterable length, and hence can be treated as O(1) it term of iterable, which is oxymoron.

Comment: @mgilson I read the (updated) question as follows: OP whants to build a generator yielding positions of a pattern in a string. Solution clearly has to iterate over all the string (independent to pattern) in worst case.

Comment: I assume indexing is constant-time, shouldn't slicing a small substring out of a much larger string also be nearly-constant time?

Comment: If it's a byte string, you can use a `memoryview`. If it's `str` or some other generic iterator, then you can use `itertools.islice`. This repeatedly calls `__next__` to advance to `start`, but in CPython the overhead is less than using a bytecode loop. Also, in CPython it uses `size_t` for the indices, which limits them to `sys.maxsize` (e.g. 2**31-1 on a 32-bit system).

Answer (score 0):

The following generator function will return the output that you requested:

```
def geniter(instring, pattern):
    start=0
    while start < len(instring):
        nxtidx = instring.find(pattern, start)
        if nxtidx != -1:
            yield nxtidx
            start = nxtidx + 1
        else:
            start = len(instring)
```

You can call it using: `g = geniter('abababab', 'abab')` and then iterate using repeated calls to `next(g)`. I don't think I can necessarily guarantee that it will run with efficiency O(m) however; about that issue, I just don't know.

Comment: the instring in your answer is finite, and it isn't necessarily in the question

Comment: Yes, I was confused by that terminology; googling "Python infinite string" doesn't return many hits. What exactly do you mean by "infinite string"? Even if you open an IO stream (which perhaps offers the potential for "infinite" length in some sense, I suppose) you always end up accessing the underlying data via a read() method in the end, which returns a finite number of bytes at one time in actual practice, and so your string input is always ultimately broken down into finite length segments by the IO library no matter what you do.